# How to get accurate gps location using gps or network in android

Tags: android

I want to get the most accurate Gps location as same as google map app but in my application its sometimes mismatching or it is showing wrong location

Here is my code:

```
private static GPSTracker singletonObject; private static Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 20000; // 20 Seconds

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public static GPSTracker getGPSTrackerObject(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    if (singletonObject == null) {
        singletonObject = new GPSTracker();
    }
    singletonObject.initializeLocationManager();
    return singletonObject;
}

private GPSTracker() {
    location = null;
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    canGetLocation = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); // don't Change provider -  Arul

}

private double decimalTrim(double value) {
    try {
        Double d = value;
        String[] splitter = d.toString().split("\\.");
        int integerValues = splitter[0].length();   // Before Decimal Count
        int decimalValues = splitter[1].length();
        if (decimalValues > 5) {
            return Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.#####").format(value));
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }catch(Exception exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return value;
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        return decimalTrim(location.getLatitude());
    }

    return 0.0;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        return decimalTrim(location.getLongitude());
    }
    return 0.0;
}


public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 */
public AlertDialog showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = null;
    // Showing Alert Message
    if (alertDialog != null) {
        alert = alertDialog.show();
    }
    return alert;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("Accuracy", "Loc:" + location.getAccuracy());
    Log.d("speed", "Loc:" + location.getSpeed());
    Log.d("provider","Loc:provider"+location.getProvider());
    Log.d("Time","Loc:time"+location.getTime());
    Log.d("LocationUpdate: ", "Loc:" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
    if (location.getAccuracy() < 100.0 && location.getSpeed() < 6.0) {
        this.location = location;

    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: [Read the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: Please suggest a best way to implement google map to get best accurate location

Comment: post your current code @agilan vc

Comment: Again, this is well [documented](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#setPriority\(int\))

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: As you asked i added my code here. Kindly give suggestion now

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a)

Answer (score 0):

`mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`
is one of the fastest and best way when using network for sure.
Also there is `mGoogleMap.setLocationSource(source);` for more custom purposes.